# Is it possible to get variable from URL with html without using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am very new to HTML, and I am trying to learn. It is just for fun, because I find it interesting, so i don´t need to learn everything there is about webpages.

I want to make a webpage where you can type in your name in a box, and then it will display "Hello name" in the same webpage.

I thought a solution could have two HTML files that are almost the same, but where one contains the form where you can fill in a name like this:

```
<form action="form.html" method="get">
<label for="name">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="12" size="15"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the other one displays that name with "Hello name". I thought i could use the GET method, so it could collect the variables from the URL, which in my case looks like this:

```
form.html?name=XXX
```

I have not been able to do this myself. I saw that it is possible to use a php script, but I do not know what that is.

Is it possible to achieve this using only "standard" html? If not, how can I do it without having to learn a new programming language?

Comment: There is no way to do it without JavaScript at least

Comment: @blazej — You can use  any language on the server without involving JS at all (unless that server-side language *is* JS).

Comment: That's right, but he's asking about no using programming language at all

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to achieve this using only "standard" html?

No, you need to use a programming language.

> If not, how can I do it without having to learn a new programming language?

Use a programming language you know already.